# Windows does not create new user - SID profilelist

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've created a new user, but it does not appear in the lock screen. After some research I read about profilelist in regedit. When I look there, there is no SID folder for the user (I've created a user `teste`).

[image]

Here is my profilelist. As you can see, there is no SID folder for the user `teste`:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The absence of a profile is normal.  Profiles are created the first time the user logs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect, Windows (you) did create a new user, you can clearly see that in the output of your `wmic` command.

The ProfileList at `HKML:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` is not a list of user accounts, it is just a list of existing profiles.

A profile is only created for a user when they first log on.

So why does your new user not appear on the lock screen?

To appear there the account has to meet certain criteria including:

- Not being disabled
- Not being listed in
  `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
  NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`
- Being a member of at least one group, maybe even the `users` group

There may be other reasons, but check these first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the account, which should require you to set a password for that account, so that it will show on the login page.